# How to create a website with xampp?

Tags: html, apache, web, xampp, webserver

I created this little html file `test.html`:

```
<p>It works!</p>
```

and try to host it with apache. I downloaded and installed XAMPP and started apache. But where to put `test.html` so i can access it in the browser?

I search now for 30 minutes but can't find anything to start with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**xampp/htdocs** folder, this is where index.html takes place.

You can access it via your browser like this: http://localhost/index.html

In order to add/view new files/projects, just add them to htdocs directory and access them via *localhost/filename* address.

Hope it works :)

Comment: Finally!! Thank you! They should make it more obvious to everyone, users shouldn't have to google it, the software should be more self explaining.

Answer (score 1):

In XAMPP root directory you can find 'htdocs' folder. You could create here a new folder for each web that you want to create and put inside your files. You can access in your browswer like:

http://localhost/test.html

http://localhost/NewFolder/test.html